# python cant read csv file downloaded from azure dev ops (utf-8)

Tags: python, csv, encoding, utf-8, utf-16

I created an azure dev ops query, and chose 'download results as csv' which gave me a csv file. If I open this csv in vscode, I can see in the bottom right corner it says `UTF-8 with BOM`

I am trying to write some python function that will read in each value of this csv file. I can not rely parsing text myself and spitting values based on the `,` comma character, because I will have values that include commas inside them.

If I open my csv in excel, everything is organized perfectly. But if I try to parse the file in python, it reads in every row as a single string separated by commas (bad)

```
from csv import reader
import csv

# read in csv, convert to map organized by 'id' as index root parent value
def read_csv_as_map(csv_filename, id_format, encodingVar):
    print('filename: '+csv_filename+', id_format: '+id_format+', encoding: '+encodingVar)
    dict={}
    dict['rows']={}
    try:
        with open(csv_filename, 'r', encoding=encodingVar) as read_obj:
            csv_reader = reader(read_obj, delimiter='\t')
            csv_cols = None
            for row in csv_reader:
                print('row=',row)
        print('done')
        return dict
    except Exception as e:
        print('err=',e)
        return {}

ads_dict = read_csv_as_map(
    csv_filename="csv_migration\\ads-test-direct-download.csv", 
    id_format='ID', 
    encodingVar='utf-8-sig'
)
```

console output:

```
filename: csv_migration\ads-test-direct-download.csv, id_format: ID, encoding: utf-8-sig
row= ['Title,State,Work Item Type,ID,12NC']
row= ['TITLE,WITH COMMAS,To Do,NAME,6034,"value,with,commas"']
done
```

**How can I read this file in python so it separates each value into a list? Instead of this single string**

I get the same result with `encodingVar='utf-8'`, should I open my csv in some app like notepadd++ and convert it to utf-16? My code works great for .csv files with utf-16 encoding, it can parse each individual value into a list no problem. why wont this work with a utf-8 DOM csv, even when excel can parse the individual values perfectly fine?

csv file: https://file.io/TXh6uyXKZaug

Comment: If it's a comma-separated file, why do you specify tabs as the delimiter? (`delimiter='\t'`)

Answer (score 0):

```
from csv import reader
import csv

# read in csv, convert to map organized by 'id' as index root parent value
def read_csv_as_map(csv_filename, id_format, encodingVar):
    print('filename: '+csv_filename+', id_format: '+id_format+', encoding: '+encodingVar)
    dict={}
    dict['rows']={}
    try:
        with open(csv_filename, 'r', encoding=encodingVar) as read_obj:
            csv_reader = reader(read_obj, delimiter='\t')
            csv_cols = None
            for row in csv_reader:
                row_as_list = row.split(",")  # <-- Gets line as list!
                print('row=',row_as_list)
        print('done')
        return dict
    except Exception as e:
        print('err=',e)
        return {}

ads_dict = read_csv_as_map(
    csv_filename="csv_migration\\ads-test-direct-download.csv", 
    id_format='ID', 
    encodingVar='utf-8-sig'
)
```

This snippet splits the line into a list that you can index to get the information out

Comment: this will not work. in my row I have a value that is `TITLE,WITH COMMAS` which includes a comma, so separating based on the comma character will provide inaccurate results

Comment: I see, will this always remain the same name (title)? If so you could manually extract it. Just trying to see the use case!

Comment: I will always have fields (multiple in fact ) that include commas and other characters, as these fields are description/comment fields from work items. if i open excel i see these fields are separated correctly. and my code works perfect for csv files encoded using utf-16, so im unsure why this utf-8 file is providing such difficulty parsing

Comment: You could save it as a TSV (tab-separated variable) instead of a CSV (comma-separated variable) and this would resolve the comma splitting issues

Comment: there is no option in excel to save as a TSV